# Binary Body Data in Post Request corrupted - Bytes change when API attempts to handle

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, api

Using serverless framework - I have an endpoint which accepts raw binary data in the body.

This endpoint seems to corrupt the data every time when attempting to save to AWS s3.

if I pass the event.body data into the s3 request - the file size is doubled (from 600kb to 1.2mb) when saved to s3 -  which in turn causes problems when downloading the file (it is a binary firmware file)

I am unsure what could be going wrong,  Why is my event.body Data changing?

First few characters of Binary File should look something like this (in hex):
<D0 F3 00 20 F9 02 09 08>

```
Attempt 1:
            const enc = new TextEncoder();
            const slice = event.body.slice(0, 10);
            console.log("bufferData", enc.encode(slice).buffer);
            // Result - D0 F3 bytes at start become 3 bytes each "ef bf bd"
            // <ef bf bd ef bf bd 00 20 ef bf bd 02 09 08>
```

```
Attempt 2
            const buff = Buffer.from(event.body, "binary");
            console.log(buff.buffer);
            // Result - D0 F3 bytes at start become fd fd
            // <fd fd 00 20 fd 02 09 08>
```

```
Edit: Attempt 3
            const arr = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < event.body.length; i += 1) {
              arr.push(event.body.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);
            }
            console.log("byteArray", arr);
//Result = 253, 253, 0, 32, 253, 2, 9, 8
// FD FD is still there (253, 253) which leads me to believe the data being sent is already incorrect when it arrives at api?
```

Comment: Are you trying to post a File from a WEB app to a hanlder that then saves the file into an Amazon S3 bucket? We have some examples of this use case that uses AJAX.

Comment: I am indeed!  its a .bin File